# Symfony mssql_connect

Tags: php

I am facing a problem with mssql_connect. I am using symfony1.1.  mssql_connect working properly in actions. But I am getting " Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" when i call mssql_connect from symfony task. Any one please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Avinash

Comment: Post your error.log files please. Also refer to these: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=197064.0

Answer (score 0):

Your php-cli binary is probably using another php.ini as your mod_php/php-cgi binary. Check the path with `php -i | grep ini` and add the mssql-extension.